# Is it safe to use a string of lights with one shattered

Tags: electrical

I have a string of bulb lights but today I accidentally shattered one of the bulbs on the string. Is it still safe to plug it into a plug if all the other bulbs are fine? (meaning they're not shattered)

Comment: It really depends on the type of light string. If Christmas tree lights with a shunted lamp(usually the tiny lamps) a piece of tape over the broken lamp may be fine but festoon lighting or larger 120v strings that have full current potential at each socket the lamp should be replaced.

Comment: Instead of running the string with one broken lamp, try unplugging the string. Then get a pair of needlenose and slowly carefully work the broken base out of the socket. Some say a carrot or potato works but I have never tried it. One the base is out then you can restring the lights, just make sure the open base is somehow protected. Another bulb would be nice.

Comment: One thing that was not asked was if the string is outside or inside. If its outside, then a tape isnt sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

It is not safe if the string is of incandescent bulbs, because there will be exposed line voltage in the broken bulb.

In that case, remove the broken bulb and plug it in. If the string lights (it.has parallel wiring; usual for large screw-in bulbs), then you're fine. If it does not light, you will need to replace the bulb (it has series wiring, usual for small push-in bulbs).

If the string works without the bulb and you don't intend to replace it, wrap electrical tape (or whatever plastic or cloth you have available) over the socket so nobody can accidentally put a finger into it.

LED strings may or may not have safe low voltage, depending on how they were designed.

Comment: Are there alternatives I can use instead of electrical tape because I don't have electrical tape

Comment: @elise Lots of people just hang it up and don't worry about it — it's not any worse than any light with multiple sockets where one is left empty — but it's a good idea to do _something_ to cover it up. Electrical tape is just one neat way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Unplug and remove the light.

If it is wired in series (some are) then none will work.  Most are wired in parallel.

If you don't have electrical tape try and cap with some something non-conductive.  Like a top to spray paint or some kitchen item.  Then tape that with what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with previous post - it depends on the type of light string.  Sounds like you just need to replace the bulb.  Unplug the lights and use a potato and/or pair of pliers to remove the cap.  If it's something else, here's a quick video about String Light Repair https://youtu.be/FBuog146jd8

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se] and Stack Exchange in general. If you'll take the [tour] and read through [how to answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), you'll note that this is a borderline "link-only" answer. When (not if) that video disappears, all the info in it goes too. If you'd please [edit] your answer to include at least a summary of the info in the video, that would take this from a good answer to a great one.